# Getting all commits on a branch that was not part of previous branches

Tags: azure-devops

using `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commitsbatch?api-version=6.1-preview.1` I can get a list of a specific branch (in this case a release branch) I would like to limit it to commits that weren't part of any previous release branches.

I tried

```
{
"compareVersion" : {
                "versionType": "branch",
                "version": "release.2"
              },
"itemVersion": {
                "versionType": "branch",
                "version": "release.1"
              }
}
```

and I've tried fromCommitId.

```
{
    "fromCommitId" : "some commit sha"
}
```

Neither seems to work

What I'm looking for is if the first branch includes

```
[
   {
      "commitId": "b1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed8"
   },{
      "commitId": "a1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed9"
   },{
      "commitId": "c1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed0"
   },{
      "commitId": "f1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed1"
   }
]
```

and the second branch contains:

```
[
   {
      "commitId": "b1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed8"
   },{
      "commitId": "a1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed9"
   },{
      "commitId": "c1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed0"
   },{
      "commitId": "f1c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed1"
   },{
      "commitId": "b2c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed1"
   },{
      "commitId": "b3c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed1"
   }
]
```

Then I only want the below returned for the second branch since the rest are also part of the first branch.

```
{
      "commitId": "b2c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed1"
   },{
      "commitId": "b3c561d96ff1808700b34b3ef5346e0df4bf5ed1"
   }
```

Comment: It's not clear about `But neither seem to work`, could you share some more details about what you met so that we can better understand your issue?  If you get response with count 0, you should check which branch is precious version. And if you're using postman to test the api, make sure you chose the `Raw with json` in `Body` settings.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT neither providing a fromCommitId nor a compareversion seem to work

Comment: What's the relationship between first branch and the second one? Do you create the second branch based on first branch? And how do you run the rest api, via Powershell or Postman or what? What's the real response do you get? `Value[]`?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT They are both branches off of trunk. I call the API from F# and I get an error back stating that the "compareVersion" doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The API works well during my test, please double-check whether it works on your side.

Commits for `Release.1` branch:

[image]

Commits for `Release.2` branch:

[image]

My body:

```
{
  "itemVersion": {
    "versionType": "branch",
    "version": "release.1"
  },
  "compareVersion": {
    "versionType": "branch",
    "version": "release.2"
  }
}
```

The Result:

[image]

[image]

I created `Release.2` branch from `Release.1` branch when `Release.1` only had two commits, then I made one commit in `Release.1` and two commits in `Release.2`. So `Release.2` has two commits(`14565a1a` and `5acd3398`) which `Release.1` doesn't contain. And it's clear that the API can work to return these two commits.